# Closing an application using WiX

Tags: wix, installation

In creating my WiX installer I have run into an issue when trying to close an application before installing the upgrade. Below is an example of how I am attempting to do this.

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseServe" CloseMessage="yes" Target="server.exe" ElevatedCloseMessage="yes" RebootPrompt="no"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>      
  <Custom Action="WixCloseApplications" After="RemoveExistingProducts" />
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
  <Custom Action='LaunchApplication' After='InstallFinalize'/>
  <!--<Custom Action='StopServer' Before='RemoveExistingProducts'/>-->
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Using this example the application does end up closing but the installation gets stalled at that point and then performs a rollback. Could this be due to the fact that the exe is removed prior to trying to close it? I have tried changing the sequence around so that RemoveExistingProducts is performed after the WixCloseApplications but it then gives me an error code 2613.

Comment: It would be great if you explain what the error finally was - the accepted answer just suggests to generate a log of the installation...

Comment: It has been so long that I honestly can't remember the full issue. The logging helped me track it down though. It was a sequence issue where you couldn't close the program in this fashion before remove existing products but you couldn't remove existing products if it was running. A bootstrapper helped me with that issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try logging the installation and see what you can track down from there. Try running the installer from the command console like so:

```
msiexec.exe /i [msi filename] /log [filepath\logfilename.log]
```

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***: [Newer sample of WiX CloseApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213101/129130)

---

I would assume that you need to close the running application as early as possible in the **InstallExecuteSequence**, and certainly before **InstallInitialize** which starts the Windows Installer transaction that makes changes to the system.

In addition you should run the same **ApplicationClose** operation in the **InstallUISequence** as well so the application is closed while you cycle through the installation menus interactively. The whole InstallUISequence is skipped when you install silently, so you need it in the InstallExecuteSequence as well.

Be aware that you can **accidentially trigger rollback** in a custom action by returning an exit code / error code that **msiexec.exe** interprets as an error. If the completion of the custom action isn't crucial, I turn off error checking to allow the install to continue. In this case that would just cause a reboot to be required.

If what you are trying to close or shut down is a **service**, MSI has built-in features to deal with this via the [ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) and [ServiceInstall](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html) elements ([and others](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html)).