# In Wix MSI: Killing a process upon uninstallation

Tags: wix, uninstallation, windows-installer

I added a custom action that should kill my application using taskkill CMD when someone tries to uninstall it using the add/remove in the control panel using the following code :

```
<Property Id="TASKKILL">
        <DirectorySearch Id="SysDir" Path="[SystemFolder]" Depth="1">
            <FileSearch Id="taskkillExe" Name="taskkill.exe" />
        </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<CustomAction Id="ServerKill" Property="TASKKILL" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" ExeCommand="/F /FI &quot;IMAGENAME EQ App.exe&quot;"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="ServerKill" After="FindRelatedProducts"/>   
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

However this does not work. If someone can tell me how to fix it or even share a better/easier way to kill my app process I would be grateful.

*p.s*
also tried to use WMIC using cmd. That really didn't work and the installation itself did not finish at all because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can try the **CloseApplication feature** from the Util schema:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html

See here for an example code snippet: https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/20186650/

---

UPDATE: I ran some tests and this element works a little differently from what I expected. The first thing you need to add is the reference to the wixUtilExtension file. On the command line this is:

```
candle -ext WiXUtilExtension Test.wxs
light -ext WixUtilExtension Test.wixobj
```

In **Visual Studio** I think you simply add a project reference to **WixUtilExtension.dll**.

Then you simply add something like this to your wxs source file:

```
  <util:CloseApplication Id="CloseNotepad" Target="notepad.exe"
                         CloseMessage="yes" RebootPrompt="no">
  </util:CloseApplication>
```

And add this at the top of your wxs file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

It looks like Wix takes care of the rest (custom actions and a custom table in your MSI with the list of processes to kill).

---

Here is my full test file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

   <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111111111" 
            Name="Example Product Name" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="Example Company Name" Language="1033">
      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Comments="Windows Installer Package"/>
      <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
 
      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
         <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="*">
        </Component>
      </Directory>
 
      <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
         <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
      </Feature>

      <util:CloseApplication Id="CloseNotepad" Target="notepad.exe" CloseMessage="yes" RebootPrompt="no"></util:CloseApplication>
   </Product>
</Wix>
```

---

***Links***: Some related or marginally related links for easy retrieval.

- [Windows Installer-Avoid FileinUse dialog box when Installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917062/windows-installer-avoid-fileinuse-dialog-box-when-installing-a-package/50935008#50935008)
- [Reboot on install, Don't reboot on uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840273/reboot-on-install-dont-reboot-on-uninstall/48842663#48842663)
- [How to kill a process upon uninstall using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238175/how-to-kill-a-process-upon-uninstall-using-wix)
- [Wix's util:CloseApplication extension doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977551/wixs-utilcloseapplication-extension-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the replay
checked it out and i cant define CloseApplication element for some unknown reason.
i get the following message : 
Setup.wxs(35) : error CNDL0200 : The Product element contains an unhandled extension element 'util:CloseApplication'.  Please ensure
 that the extension for elements in the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension' namespace has been provided.
WixUI_InstallDirNoLicense.wxs
light.exe : error LGHT0093 : Could not find entry section in provided list of intermediates. Expected section of type 'Product'.

Comment: I added some detail to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively a simple VBScript scheduled to run on uninstall should do the job:

```vb
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Notepad.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```